# Using specified strings.xml

Tags: android, multilingual, android-resources

I have two different `strings.xml` for multi-language app. Where can I set that I want to use English `strings.xml` file independent of phone locale language always but use Chinese language only in case when on splash screen we have chosen it?

Comment: Have you read this [support-languages](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages)

Comment: Do you want to support choosing language in your app?

Comment: @Bracadabra yes, simply I need to open app with strings.xml that will conform to selected on start screen language.

Answer (score 1):

To support language setting in your application you need to change current configuration and restart activity to reload all resources. You can change current configuration like this:

```
void changeLanguage(Context context, String language) {
    final Locale locale = new Locale(language);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    final Resources res = context.getResources();
    final Configuration config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());
    config.setLocale(locale);
    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

And then don't forget to recreate your activity `activity.recreate();` or reload your resources manually.

Also you need to set your locale on every process start. You can do it in application onCreate:

```
public void YourApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        changeLanguage(this, getLanguageSettingsFromPreferences());
    }
}
```